# Seekbar with textview in a listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, custom-adapter

So i was try to use seekbar to get progress value in a custom adapter for the listview. everything was fine on the code, however when i try to launch it, the automaticcaly close and go to previous activity. can anyone know what is the problems in my code ?

i am using the sharedpreferences for other activity in the app in the future, so thats why im using it.

here the custom adapter code

```
public class PerrowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Perrow> {

    int textSize = 30;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;
    private ArrayList<Perrow> objects;

    public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvArabic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabictext);
        TextView tvTransliteration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
        TextView tvTranslation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation);

        //seekbar

        int progress = sharedPreferences.getInt("progress", 0);
        
        SeekBar seekbar1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekbar1.setProgress(progress);

        //settextsize
        tvArabic.setTextSize(textSize+seekbar1.getProgress()); // size 30sp

        Perrow perrow = objects.get(position);

        tvArabic.setText(perrow.getArabic());
        tvTransliteration.setText(perrow.getTransliteration());
        tvTranslation.setText(perrow.getTranslation());

        //seekbar

        seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progressNew = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
                progressNew = progress;
                tvArabic.setTextSize(textSize);
                editor.putInt("progress", progress);
                editor.apply();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

here the error log

```
2021-02-27 23:05:26.130 3959-3959/? E/example.munaja: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-27 23:05:26.148 3959-3959/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "runtime.mmitest.isrunning"
2021-02-27 23:05:26.345 3959-3995/com.example.munajat E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@b449e48
```

and here is the activity java

```
public class fontsize extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    //SharedPreferences

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    ListView listView;


    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fontsize);

        //sharedpreferences

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        //seekbar

        String[] arabic = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fontsize);
        String[] transliteration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transliteration);
        String[] translation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.translation);


        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Create Data

        ArrayList<Perrow> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arabic.length; i++){
            list.add(new Perrow(arabic[i], transliteration[i], translation[i]));
        }



        ///customadapter

        PerrowAdapter perrowAdapter = new PerrowAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, list);
        listView.setAdapter(perrowAdapter);


        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout4);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view4);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(fontsize.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and from run terminal i got this

```
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6c623a
V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{50930bb token=android.os.BinderProxy@6c623a {com.example.munajat/com.example.munajat.fontsize}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@6c623a
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=com.example.munajat, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
I/BlockMonitor: dispatchingThrewException In MainThread
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
    [PatchStore] create disable file for com.example.munajat uid is 10425
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.munajat, PID: 9485
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.munajat.PerrowAdapter.getView(PerrowAdapter.java:57)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2494)
        at android.widget.HwAbsListView.obtainView(HwAbsListView.java:1139)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1446)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1352)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:355)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:636)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:407)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:446)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:178)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:849)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:728)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:849)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:728)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:896)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24742)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8089)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1057)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:875)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1042)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9485 SIG: 9
```

and the main activity i use to launch the font size activity

```
public class maintext extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    int textSize = 30;

    TextView textView;

    //sharedpreferencesvariables

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintext);

        // definingtextview

        textView = findViewById(R.id.maintext);

        //sharedpreferencescall

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);

        int progress = prefs.getInt("progress",0);

        //settextsizeaccordingseekbar

        textView.setTextSize(textSize+progress);


        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout1);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view1);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(maintext.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(maintext.this, fontsize.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                finish();

        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you share the crash report?

Comment: it just suddenly close.. but here the error log , i put it on edit on the post

Comment: is your app geting crashed on changing seekbar value or it doesnt even open.

Comment: the whole activity doesnt even open, it suddenly stop and go back to prev activity

Comment: i updated the questions as it just automatically close

Comment: use getApplicationContext() or getActivity() instead of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
       PerrowAdapter perrowAdapter = new PerrowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(perrowAdapter);
```

Add break keyword:

```
    case R.id.nav_home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(fontsize.this, home.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_fontsize:
           break;
    }
```

Doing this should work:

```
    SeekBar seekbar1 = (SeekBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);//typecast the seekbar
```

First of all try this on your onprogresschanged:

```
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(progress!=null){
            textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
            progressNew = progress;
            tvArabic.setTextSize(textSize);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        editor.putInt("progress", progress);
            editor.apply();

        }
    });
```

The problem with your code is that you have added NavigationItemselected in your fontsize activity instead of adding it in your mainActivity. After doing this you need to send an intent to your fontsize activity and your home activity in your NavigationItemselected.

### Edit

```
   private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
private ArrayList<Perrow> objects;
 TextView tvArabic;
    TextView tvTransliteration;
    TextView tvTranslation;
public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> objects, TextView tvArabic,
    TextView tvTransliteration,
    TextView tvTranslation) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource = resource;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.tvArabic=tvArabic;
    this.tvTransliteration=tvTransliteration;
   this.tvTranslation=tvTranslation;
}
```

Comment: mashaallah thank you brother for the answer, but it does not work.

Comment: i already set the adapter in the activity

Comment: doesnt work sir.. ill tried your solution, but i really appreciate your answers

Comment: I got it sir, i thought the the code will find seekbar on font activity, however it will find from resources stated which is list_row layout. After set a seekbar on the stated resources layout, it works. However, i actually wanted it to use the seekbar from the font activity layout. Really appreciate an answers if you know it.

Comment: But i want to change each textview size in listview seperately using seperate seekbar. Can i call textview from list_row layout in font size activity?

Comment: Did you mean that the textview which is in your adapter class to fontsize activity.

Comment: Yess sir can i just convert view and use it?

Comment: Yes you can do it by adding your textview as parameter in your perrowadapter constructor and then doing the same for your textview as you have done for other parameter inside your constructor scope.You need to declare the textview globally.Then you need to call the adapter in your fontsize activity and pass the textview.

Comment: In sha Allah  i will share code tommorrow since i m very tired today.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: You just need to use the make instance of adapter wherever you want to use the textview.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the constructor, you should add the next lines:

```
this.sharedPreferences = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
this.editor = this.sharedPreferences.edit();
```

if you haven't done it & you haven't created a SharedPreferences filed with the name that replaces SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME your app will crash again because it will be a null object reference of this.shared preferences while getting the editor of a null value.

Comment: im sorry but can you explain more detail ?

Comment: i include the activity java please take a look

Comment: Yes, I mean, the code crashes because you didn't assign any value into the SP property and into the Editor property too, you should assign the SP file you have in your app by getting it as I mentioned above. else, the code will crash all over again every time you'll run it.

Comment: And one more thing, you should enable the editing of the int value before editing it, add the next line in the onProgressChange function: editor.edit();

Comment: im sorry but isnt editor edit is to apply the value on the textview ?  shouldnt it be put on other activity that needed the value ?

Comment: im sorry but if u dont mind can you provide the code ?

Comment: I'll write it down for you in an answer, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: thank you very much reallly appreciate it sir

Comment: you are welcome mate, I read it again and saw that it isn't necessary because I already told you to do it, I'll write you the code anyway.

Comment: Also, check if the value of (int) progress isn't null in any way, you must put a numeral value into seekbar.setProgress()..

Comment: it still suddenly stop sir, its not working.. or do i need to do something with the main activity code ? or put position in the settextsize ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public PerrowAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Perrow> 
objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource = resource;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.sharedPreferences = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences("progress", 
    MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup 
parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView tvArabic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabictext);
    TextView tvTransliteration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.transliteration);
    TextView tvTranslation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation);

    //seekbar

    int progress = sharedPreferences.getInt("progress", 0);
    
    SeekBar seekbar1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
    seekbar1.setProgress(progress);

    //settextsize
    tvArabic.setTextSize(textSize+seekbar1.getProgress()); // size 30sp

    Perrow perrow = objects.get(position);

    tvArabic.setText(perrow.getArabic());
    tvTransliteration.setText(perrow.getTransliteration());
    tvTranslation.setText(perrow.getTranslation());

    //seekbar

    seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressNew = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
            this.editor = this.sharedPreferences.edit();
            progressNew = progress;
            tvArabic.setTextSize(textSize);
            this.editor.putInt("progress", progress);
            this.editor.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: im sorry sir, but the activity still stop suddenly and go back to prev activity..

Comment: have u added break keyword in your navigation onnavigationitemselected

Comment: Danish is right, you should add a break keyword in the main activity navigation.

Comment: I don't know sir, can you screenshot the error displayed in the run terminal?

Comment: oh sorry wait sir

Comment: Have you tried to look for it on google ? I saw there a bunch of docu's and questions about it, maybe you'll find something useful

Comment: idk sir,  ill checked all questions already